# why material icon not horizontally centered with in span

Tags: css, icons, alignment

i am using merterial symbol rounded icon along with bootstrap, in image slider i am using back and forward arrows, forward arrow are center align (horizotally) with in the span but back arrow is not, see the screen shot[see red border of span](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlYG7.png)

```
<button class="carousel-control-next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <span class="material-symbols-rounded">
                  arrow_forward_ios
                </span>
                
                
              </span>
            </button>

<button class="carousel-control-prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"> 
                <span class="material-symbols-rounded">
                  arrow_back_ios
                </span></span>
            </button>



.carousel-control-prev > span {
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 1px #F0F0F0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

i am trying to center aling horizontally the meterial icons

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is only applied to `.carousel-control-prev > span`, not the `.carousel-control-next > span` element.

That doesn't totally make sense looking at your screenshot, but I think it's safe to say that you should revisit the CSS there and make sure you're doing the same thing to both icons.

Maybe try:

```
.carousel-control-prev > span,
.carousel-control-next > span {
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 1px #F0F0F0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Also, the way your CSS is written means that the styles are applied to the span that wraps the icon's span, not the icon's span itself. That might also be worth looking at.